# Nearest neighbor search for points with directional vectors caveat

Tags: nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a set of 3D points, each of which is associated with a direction (e.g. a unit vector). Given another point + direction I would like to figure out the closest point in the set (using standard 2-norm) that also satisfies a certain condition on direction vectors (e.g. the angle between the two direction vectors is within a certain angular amount). So far I have a KD-tree based range search on the 3D points and then check whether any of such points fit within the angular constraints, but realize this is a highly unoptimized hack. Was wondering if there's an obvious better way to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also include details on roughly the number of points you are dealing with? And how fast/slow is your current algorithm? What are you trying to optimize for? Speed? Memory? Code clarity? My first instinct is to try formulate this as a convex optimization problem as the function that returns the closest point to a set of points is a convex function and your constraint appears to be a linear one.

Comment: Roughly dealing with 8k to 15K points. Would love to optimize for speed - memory is definitely not an issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To me the main problem in your current formulation is that the angular comparison is kernelized (i.e requires a comparison between vectors). If you expand the orientation of each angle to a separate 2D vector (cos theta, sin theta) then you should just be able to do another nearest neighbour search with a limited radius in this space (KDTree should be fine) and take the intersection of the two result sets.

Comment: 3D direction should be broken into 3D vector(cos(phi)*cos(theta), cos(phi)*sin(theta), sin(phi)) right? i.e. a point on the unit sphere.

Comment: @wcochran what you suggest differs slightly from the polar->cartesian formula quoted on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system but it might well still be valid. My trig / algebra too rusty to tell quickly if they're equivalent.

Comment: From Wikipedia - Cartesian coordinates may be retrieved from the spherical coordinates (radius r, inclination θ, azimuth φ), where r = 1, θ ∈ [0, π], φ ∈ [0, 2π), by
x = r cos φ sin  θ, y = r sin φ sin  θ,  z = r cos θ

Answer (score 1):

Consider using R*-trees. This data structure based on rectangles is quite amenable to complex queries.

I.e. if you can check whether a *rectangle may contain points that satisfy your constraints* then the R*-tree can be used to accelerate this query. The indexes in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) are extensible, so that may be a good starting point. From my understanding, you should be able to formulate this as a distance function in ELKI, as in [this tutorial in their wiki](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SpatialDistanceFunctions): if the rectangle cannot satisfy the constraints, you return an infinite distance.

Answer (score 1):

You posted long ago, but I'm working on a similar problem and found some answers, so I'll post and hope it's still of some use.

This is called in the literature *constrained nearest neighbor search*.  [This paper](http://delab.csd.auth.gr/~alex/sdb/stanoi.pdf) has a nice section on how it works on R-trees, even though the paper is about something else.

Your KD-tree is a good starting point. The algorithm in the paper for R trees will work as well for the KD-tree case.

The paper describes a specialized version of normal nearest neighbor search that's as follows.

Start by building a depth-first search that will traverse all the cells containing at least one point satisfying the caveat.  The search should visit cells in order of increasing *mindist* from the query point.  *mindist* is distance from query point to closest point in the cell.

Now modify the traversal to skip descent into cells with *mindist* larger than the best point (closest to the query and satisfying the caveat) found so far.